# Adding a Flask class instance into a LoginManager Class instance

Tags: python, class, flask, module, instance

I cant find anywhere a good explanation for a beginner what exactly happens when I pass the Flask class instance into the LoginManager class instance from the flask_login module.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
```

Per my understanding the "app" is an instance of the class Flask. Also login_manager is an instance of the class LoginManager (from another module). How comes, that I can easily pass a whole class into a different (module) class? What exactly happens here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.

in the `login_manager = LoginManager(app)` we have created an instance of the class LoginManager and passed the app class, which is an instance of Flask. The reason behind this is, we can use the methods of the app instance from within the login_manger instance now. Hence we can extend functionalities of the app.

Best was to understand this was to reproduce this in small exercise files.

Here my example:

File 1 (This will serve as example for Flask Module):

```
class FirstClass:
def _init_(self):
    pass
def say_1(self):
    print("Hello First Class")

def _repr_(self):
    print("hello from first class")
```

File 2 (This will serve for example of LoginManager Module):

```
class SecondClass:
def _init_(self, x):
    self.x = x
    pass
def say_2(self):
    print("Hello Second Class")
```

File 3 (from which we run the app):

```
from first import FirstClass
from second import SecondClass

one = FirstClass()
two = SecondClass(one)
```